# How to automatically enable notification on calendar events in Lotus Notes?

Tags: calendar, lotus-notes

Is there a way to automatically enable the 'Notify me' in 30 minutes on all calendar invitations that I accept in Lotus Notes?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. Go to File > Preferences > Calendar and to do > Alarms > check "Display Alarm notification > check Appoints/meetings and enter the number of minutes ahead of time you want to be notified.